# Revert expansion of "nested" polynomial; eg, from $x^4+2x^3+5x^2+4x+4$ to $(x+x^2)^2+4(x+x^2)+4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, polynomials

Say I have a polynomial $P$:

$$\left(x+x^{2}\right)^{2}+4\left(x+x^{2}\right)+4$$

"Expanding" the above would give us:

$$x^{4}+2x^{3}+5x^{2}+4x+4$$

My question is, how do I do the reverse of this process, so that when I start with the expanded form, I could go back to the original form?

If possible, please provide an explanation for a purely general case. I'd also like to point out that this is not, in any way, a homework question.

Comment: well whenever I see $x^4+2x^3$ it motivates me to complete the square

Comment: For information on factoring polynomial,  check out: 
 https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_root_theorem

Comment: *"If possible, please provide an explanation for a purely general case."* What's the "general case" here? Are you asking how to express an arbitrary polynomial as a polynomial specifically in $x+x^2$ (ie, $p(x)=q(x+x^2)$)? Or are you asking how to express an arbitrary polynomial as a polynomial in yet another arbitrary polynomial (ie, $p(x)=q(r(x))$)?

Comment: What is your motivation?  Solving the quartic equation, or factoring quartic polynomial? Because if you do $x ^ 2 + x = t$, you will reduce the degree of the quartic polynomial.  Am I guessing right?  Is your goal to solve the quartic equation?  If so, you cannot convert the **any** quartic polynomial to the quadratic polynomial directly.  This is impossible.  This only works in special cases for special polynomials.

Comment: @Blue ideally, the latter, because limiting us to the case of $x^2+x$ wouldn't be too thrilling. Otherwise, I'm okay with just sticking to $x^2+x$.

Comment: @lonestudent please note that this is just a pure maths question. I'm sure that there are much better ways to solve a quartic equation.

Comment: @MarwanAmireh: Please [edit your question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/4010824/edit) to include clarifying details. Comments are easily overlooked (and may be hidden from some readers). .., Another nuance: Are you given both $p(x)$ and $r(x)$, and then asking for $q(x)$ (if it exists) such that $p(x)=q(r(x))$? or are you given only $p(x)$ and are asking for both $r(x)$ and $q(x)$ (if they exist)?

Comment: @Blue I was hoping that we can get $r(x)$ and $q(x)$ from just $p(x)$ (kind of like partial fraction decomposition, for the lack of a better example), but then I realized that there may be many combinations of $r(x)$ and $q(x)$ so that $q(r(x))=p(x)$ (the functions are not invertible). The problem is that I assumed that $p(x)$ only maps from $q(r(x))$ and nothing else.